# Get value of date picker in PHP code

Tags: php, javascript, date

I have a form that contains a date picker. The date picker works fine, but when I want to submit its value to the PHP script it, doesn't show. Here is the relevant part of my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <form action="sub.php" method="post">
        <h2>JsDatePick's Javascript Calendar usage example</h2>

        Look at the comments on the HTML source to fully understand how this very simple example works.

        <input type="text" size="12" id="inputField" name="inputField" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

And I want to pick the date value from `inputField` in this script:

```
<?php
    echo $date=$_POST['inputField'];
?>
```

So can you guys tell me how can I get this value from the HTML to the PHP script? I did not show the code of the date picker because that works fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing your closing `</form>` tag

Comment: no i am not showing the full html code

Comment: When you click the input field then click a date on the calendar, does the date actually appear in the textbox?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` And see what's inside.

Comment: @D.Strout yes it shows correct value

Comment: well a missing form tag could cause this problem so you should fix your example if it isn't the real code. Likely there's something wrong in code you aren't showing

Comment: @HarshalMahajan Form is not submitted correctly in that case. Check your html.

Comment: Thanks to all,it is solved now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    $date = $_POST['inputField'];
    echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but the php code is not an issue.i solved it.

Comment: You should answer your own question, just in case somebody else stumbles across this thread.

Comment: actually it was my mistake i forget to close </form> tag.i don't think it is like a thread and should be answered.

Answer (score 0):

this is the datepicker

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="date" name="date">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and all the PHP code you need to get up and running is this

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $date = $_POST['date'];
      echo $date;
  }

?>
```

this code   `$date = $_POST['date'];` gets the value of the date picker

and this code `echo $date;` prints out the date you picked